# Why do I not need to specify autoresizingMask for my custom UIViewController's root view?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autoresizingmask

In my custom view controller I override `loadView` to programmatically set up my view hierarchy. To support auto-rotation I assign an appropriate value to the `autoresizingMask` property of all views in the hierarchy - except for the root view (the one that I assign to `self.view`). Despite this omission, resizing on auto-rotation works perfectly (it feels *so* good to be finally able to say this ☺). I have tested in various simulators, and also on my iPhone and iPad devices.

Does anyone know why this is the case? Is this behaviour just "luck", or is it officially documented by Apple somewhere?

(Note: I'm asking mostly out of curiosity, please don't tell me to "go fix it, it's just one line of code" - I have already done so.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autoresizesSubviews`/`autoresizingMask` define a superview-to-subview relationship. In the case of a `UIViewController` that supports rotation, the controller is managing the view's frame on rotation independent of any autoresize properties.

Comment: Sounds good. I also found the following statement in Apple's UIViewController class documentation: "When a view controller is displayed on screen, its root view is typically resized to fit the available space, which can vary depending on the window’s current orientation and the presence of other interface elements such as the status bar." So I guess, setting `autoreszingMask` on the root view is not necessary after all.