# UIView size is not as expected to be

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I can't figure out why that view takes the entire screen.

In AppDelegate file

...

```
self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
[self.window setRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

..

In ViewController.m

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 30, 30)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
self.view = view;
```

When I run the app the screen is entirely green instead of having just a square in green.
What is wrong here ?

Comment: where do you set `self.view = view`?

Comment: I can't understand what you ask.

Comment: Where do you the second snippet of code? In `loadView` method? But as Richard J. Ross III suggested, maybe you need to use (for example) `[self.window addSubview:view];`

Comment: It is in loadView method. I tried with [self.window addSubview] But the app crash and gdb prints  "Unable to restore previously selected frame" message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The erroneous line is here:

```
self.view = view;
```

When you set a view of a `UIViewController` that is the root controller, it is guaranteed to fill the screen. Instead, add it as a subview:

```
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

And you should be fine.

Comment: When I change to [self.view addSubview:view] the app crash and I get "Unable to restore previously selected frame" error in gdb

Answer (score 0):

The view controller automatically manages the size of its root view (`self.view`), so even if you initialize it with a smaller size it will later get resized to fill the screen. This resizing conveniently also happens when the interface orientation changes (see the answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039991/why-do-i-not-need-to-specify-autoresizingmask-for-my-custom-uiviewcontrollers-r)).

As suggested by Richard's answer, you can add your green view as a subview to the controller's root view. The crash you get is probably because the root view does not exist yet when you try to access it. Try the following:

```
- (void) loadView
{
  [super loadView];  // creates the root view

  UIView* subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 30, 30)];
  [subView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
  // because you don't set any autoresizingMask, subView will stay the same size

  [self.view addSubview:subView];
}
```